# How to handle the request when the user clicks the not now button during login with facebook

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

When i **click "Not Now" button**

during login with facebook it sends me to the previous url along with status code

```
https://localhost:3000/facebook/redirect?error=access_denied&error_code=200&error_description=Permissions+error&error_reason=user_denied#_=_
```

Can someone tell me how I can customize this URL if the user clicks on the not now button then we will redirect to some other url like localhost:3000/deauthUrl?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "customize"? Other than specifying your `redirect_uri`, you can not modify anything here. If you want to show the user specific feedback for this specific case - then your script that gets triggered via `/facebook/redirect`, needs to evaluate the URL parameters it got passed, and react accordingly ...

Comment: customize means whenever the user clicks the "Not now" button we will redirect the user to some other url like localhost:3000/deauthUrl...

Comment: Facebook only sends the user back to that one `redirect_uri` you specified when invoking the login dialog. You will have to handle the result from there.